# Declare a string in elisp and then inserting it in emacs lisp

Tags: elisp

I want to create i string and then insert it, but i get the error wrong argument char-or-stringp. What does it mean?

```
(defun test ()

   (string "1 2 3")
 )


(insert (test))
```

Comment: I get `(wrong-type-argument characterp)` from your code, not the error you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string` call is incorrect.  `"1 2 3"` *is* already a string.  You seem to be looking for simply

```lisp
(insert "1 2 3")
```

or if you want to demonstrate a function call,

```lisp
(defun test ()
  "1 2 3")

(insert (test))
```

The `string` form expects a sequence of characters, like this:

```lisp
(string ?1 ? ?2 ? ?3)
=> "1 2 3"
```